# Show menu on specific page

Tags: 7

I created a menu with one specific menu entry. I want to show the menu only on one page.

Does exist a module which places a menu like a block?

Comment: Menu block solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the aptly named [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.

> ...provides configurable blocks of menu trees starting with any level of any menu.